# Drupal 6 backport of Drupal 7 admin-bar and overlay?

Tags: drupal-6, admin, drupal-7

Hey people!  I don't like Drupal 7 because, well, it doesn't seem to work (or maybe the modules I need don't work, but the fact is I can't develop with it)

What I do like is the nifty new admin interface & overlay do-dad.  Is there anything out there that is all awesome like that?  Admin menu is decent (arguably better, even), but it's a lot uglier (I want this for client pleasure purposes) and doesn't do the overlay thing.

So:

- is there a way to make admin-menu look as nice as d7s admin-bar?
- is there a way to do that overlay trick in d6?

While I'll upvote deep hacks to do this, I'm looking for a module or some other hour or so type solution.

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no backport of these two modules for now.

About the toolbar, you can see a [Comparison of Toolbar/Top/Administration Menus](http://groups.drupal.org/node/28912).

You should also try the [admin](http://drupal.org/project/admin) module wich display links in a sidebar that you can close/open.

A backport of the overlay is nearly impossible to make because this module uses some Drupal 7 new features like [path_get_admin_paths()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/path_get_admin_paths/7) or [hook_library()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_library/7)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that you will be able to achieve something as nice as D7 in D6, however you may want to check out the [admin module](http://drupal.org/project/admin) as Haza mentioned for an admin type menu (this can be set to have different alignments, like left or top).

For the overlay, you could give http://drupal.org/project/modalframe a try.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a first version of Overlay for Drupal 6, it works awesome!!! well, there is some stuff to finish :P.

Please have a look!

http://drupal.org/sandbox/ruloweb/1438294

Thanks!!